# \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Imaging\Gifbuilder no image generated

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I am trying to use `GIFBUILDER` with php, but no image is generated.

Here my php code, based on the example in GifBuilder.php

```php
    public function gifBuilder(array $fileArray)
    {
        $gifCreator = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Imaging\Gifbuilder::class);
        $gifCreator->init();
        $theImage ='';
        if ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['gdlib']) { 
            $gifCreator->start($fileArray, $this->data);
            $theImage = $gifCreator->gifBuild();
            error_log("Setup: ".var_export($theImage, true),0);
            } 
    //      return $gifCreator->getImageDimensions($theImage); 
        return $theImage;
    }
```

I have a question to the example code. I don't understand why the return value should be "getImageDimension"? I changed it to `$theImage`, because I think, that should be the generated image.
But anyway, there will be no image generated.

Here the `$fileArray`, which is send to the function:

```php
    [16-Nov-2020 20:10:25 Europe/Berlin] Config: array (
    'file' => 'typo3conf/ext/imagetext/Resources/Public/Images/Plattenteller.jpg',
    'file.' => 
    array (
      'maxW' => 200,
      'maxH' => 200,
    ),
    )
```

I also tried it with this array:

```php
    [16-Nov-2020 20:09:29 Europe/Berlin] Config: array (
      'file' => 'GIFBUILDER',
      'file.' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'jpg',
        'XY' => '3157,1929',
        'width' => '500',
        1 => 'IMAGE',
        '1.' => 
        array (
          'file' => 'typo3conf/ext/imagetext/Resources/Public/Images/Plattenteller.jpg',
        ),
        4 => 'CROP',
        '4.' => 
        array (
          'crop' => '400,400,1000,1000',
        ),
        5 => 'SCALE',
        '5.' => 
        array (
          'width' => '400',
        ),
        10 => 'TEXT',
        '10.' => 
        array (
          'text' => 'Country-Musik',
          'offset' => '5,30',
          'fontColor' => 'yellow',
          'fontSize' => '20',
          'niceText' => '1',
        ),
      ),
    )
```

But both arrays don't create an output.

I hope somebody can help me!

**Edit:**

I am using Typo V9.5.22

The second example with the CROP I have got working with Typoscript.

Comment: please insert your TYPO3 version. Have you tried your image configuration in pure typoscript?

Comment: @Bernd see edit above